# split one or more record from a colums record with specific element

Tags: mysql, sql, database-schema

I'll explain myself a little better: i'm opposite from a disaster committed by the programmer before me. There is a field named title that inside divided by comma more tags I need to take the id field of the record, do a split of strings and get two or multiple records with each primary key and id taken by commas.

I insert a screen of the situation. can you help me?
[link image from the database situation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1NKM8MZ68y5cXZoSHFmb05NTjg/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function.

```
SELECT 'Codice appalti, Adeguamento prezzi' AS field, SUBSTRING_INDEX('Codice appalti, Adeguamento prezzi',',',-1) AS parta, SUBSTRING_INDEX('Codice appalti, Adeguamento prezzi',',',1) AS partb
```

OUTPUT

```
+------------------------------------+--------------------+----------------+
| field                              | parta              | partb          |
+------------------------------------+-------------+-----------------------+
| Codice appalti, Adeguamento prezzi | Adeguamento prezzi | Codice appalti |
+------------------------------------+--------------------+----------------+
```